# How can I pre-format a phone number field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, field

I'd like to have a phone number text field pre-formatted for a 10 digit number, like so (pipes not included, just delimiting field):

```
|(   )    -    |
```

and have the numbers the user enters fill in appropriately

```
|(804) 479-1832|
```

I found a good script for formatting correctly as the digits are entered [here](http://www.tutorialdash.com/tutorial/javascript/basics/view/How-to-Auto-Format-And-Mask-Telephone-Numbers-with-Javascript_44084), but nothing yet that delivers a preformatted structure.

Is there a simple library or link for this? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-format structured data (phone, date) using jQuery plugin (or failing that vanilla JavaScript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109854/auto-format-structured-data-phone-date-using-jquery-plugin-or-failing-that-v)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check [this](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) Masked Input Plugin. It seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Pretty cool, even though I don't like the idea of putting that format there, it can look confusing if you edit numbers in the middle of the phone

Comment: any solution which doesn't involve a plugin ?

Comment: @user2929588: check this other question to see if helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery