# Phone mask with jQuery and Masked Input Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, mask, maskedinput

I have a problem masking a phone input with jQuery and [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

There are 2 possible formats:

1. `(XX)XXXX-XXXX`
2. `(XX)XXXXX-XXXX`

Is there any way to mask it accepting both cases?

EDIT:

I tried:

```
$("#phone").mask("(99) 9999-9999"); 
$("#telf1").mask("(99) 9999*-9999");    
$("#telf1").mask("(99) 9999?-9999");
```

But it doesn't works as I would like.

The closest one was (xx)xxxx-xxxxx.

I would like to get (xx)xxxx-xxxx when I type the 10th number, and (xx)xxxxx-xxxx when I type the 11th. Is it posible?

Comment: JHispa: please edit your answer, instead of adding code as a comment

Comment: @JHispa What plug-in are you using?

Comment: Zoltan, I tried this, but isn't okay. With this, I get (11) 11111-111 instead (11)xxxx-xxxx.

Comment: What do you mean Mike? I'm using jquery on a html form.

Comment: You're probably using http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/. jQuery doesn't come with a built in mask function as far as I'm aware

Comment: try https://unmanner.github.io/imaskjs/

Comment: @Rondel your link is not working, please correct or remove it from here.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/dKRGE/3/

```
$("#phone").mask("(99) 9999?9-9999");

$("#phone").on("blur", function() {
    var last = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1 );

    if( last.length == 3 ) {
        var move = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") - 1, 1 );
        var lastfour = move + last;
        var first = $(this).val().substr( 0, 9 );

        $(this).val( first + '-' + lastfour );
    }
});
```

Comment: @OscarJara You can test it in JSFiddle

Comment: +1 for your effort, but there is no difference between what it does and what the plugin does. `$("#phone").mask("(999) 99999 - 999?9")`

Comment: @Raminson - there is a difference. That mask still makes the final  number XXXXX-XXX instead of XXXX-XXXX http://jsfiddle.net/dKRGE/8/

Comment: it will cause confusion at the user
why user shoud press right key? how can they know about it?

Comment: it may be done by plugin, implementing your own placeholder, like `$.mask.definitions['@']='[0-9 ]';`

Comment: If I put Required in the input field when the page loads the input box is highlighted.  Any thoughts?  Code: <input type="text" id="phone" required />

Comment: how can we remove character limit?

Answer (score 27):

Here is a jQuery phone number mask. No plugin required.
Format can be adjusted to your needs.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VpNMA/2560/).

HTML

```
<form id="example-form" name="my-form">
    <input id="phone-number" name="phone-number" type="text" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#phone-number', '#example-form')

.keydown(function (e) {
    var key = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    $phone = $(this);

    // Don't let them remove the starting '('
    if ($phone.val().length === 1 && (key === 8 || key === 46)) {
        $phone.val('('); 
        return false;
    } 
    // Reset if they highlight and type over first char.
    else if ($phone.val().charAt(0) !== '(') {
        $phone.val('('+$phone.val()); 
    }

    // Auto-format- do not expose the mask as the user begins to type
    if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
        if ($phone.val().length === 4) {
            $phone.val($phone.val() + ')');
        }
        if ($phone.val().length === 5) {
            $phone.val($phone.val() + ' ');
        }           
        if ($phone.val().length === 9) {
            $phone.val($phone.val() + '-');
        }
    }

    // Allow numeric (and tab, backspace, delete) keys only
    return (key == 8 || 
            key == 9 ||
            key == 46 ||
            (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
            (key >= 96 && key <= 105)); 
})

.bind('focus click', function () {
    $phone = $(this);

    if ($phone.val().length === 0) {
        $phone.val('(');
    }
    else {
        var val = $phone.val();
        $phone.val('').val(val); // Ensure cursor remains at the end
    }
})

.blur(function () {
    $phone = $(this);

    if ($phone.val() === '(') {
        $phone.val('');
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't account for if the user backspaces all the way to the beginning of the input.

It also doesn't allow the user to cmd+a or ctrl+a to select the whole thing (to delete or copy it)

Comment: Updated code and fiddle so backspacing all the way is disallowed.

Comment: @Cooleshwar - It was just because the included version of jQuery was so old. I updated jQuery to v3.3.1 and it works fine in IE 11 now.

Comment: It works just fine. Much better than adding new dependency!

Answer (score 5):

Actually the correct answer is on http://jsfiddle.net/HDakN/

Zoltan answer will allow user entry "(99) 9999" and then leave the field incomplete

```
$("#phone").mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");


$("#phone").on("blur", function() {
    var last = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1 );

    if( last.length == 5 ) {
        var move = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1, 1 );

        var lastfour = last.substr(1,4);

        var first = $(this).val().substr( 0, 9 );

        $(this).val( first + move + '-' + lastfour );
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 5):

**You need a jQuery plugin for the mask works as well.**

-- HTML --

```
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(99) 9999-9999">
<input type="text" id="telf1" placeholder="(99) 9999*-9999">
<input type="text" id="telf2" placeholder="(99) 9999?-9999">
```

-- JAVASCRIPT --

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/master/src/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
    $("#phone").mask("(99) 9999-9999"); 
    $("#telf1").mask("(99) 9999*-9999");    
    $("#telf2").mask("(99) 9999?-9999"); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code has a major vulnerability. Never add code directly from the latest branch. They could update anything and it would immediately show on your site. A versioned approach is better, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/bb89c434e72030ce520764060f74b85b7ddce76e/dist/jquery.mask.min.js

Comment: They tell exactly the opposite. The latest always has the fixes of the last vulnerability. Now the big question : Who came before, the egg or the chicken?

Comment: No, you're not getting my point. It's not about fixing their bugs from a potential vulnerability, rather you are allowing code on your site that is directly from the author of the library w/o a version. If they release one malicious line of code, your site would be done. Also, if they have issues in their latest release your site could fail. This is why using versioned software is key.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the phone alias with Inputmask v3

```
$('#phone').inputmask({ alias: "phone", "clearIncomplete": true });
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="tel"]').inputmask({ alias: "phone", "clearIncomplete": true });
});
```

```html
<label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input name="phone" type="tel">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/Inputmask@3.3.7/dist/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/Inputmask@3.3.7/dist/inputmask/inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/Inputmask@3.3.7/dist/inputmask/inputmask.numeric.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/Inputmask@3.3.7/dist/inputmask/inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/Inputmask@3.3.7/dist/inputmask/inputmask.phone.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/Inputmask@3.3.7/dist/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/RobinHerbots/Inputmask@3.3.7/dist/inputmask/phone-codes/phone.js"></script>
```

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#aliases

Comment: I started to use this plugin. It works very good and it is up to date. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery Mask Plugin there is two possible ways to implement it:

1- Following Anatel's recomendations:
https://gist.github.com/3724610/5003f97804ea1e62a3182e21c3b0d3ae3b657dd9

2- Or without following Anatel's recomendations:
https://gist.github.com/igorescobar/5327820

All examples above was coded using jQuery Mask Plugin and it can be downloaded at:
http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Answer (score 1):

```
var $phone = $("#input_id");
var maskOptions = {onKeyPress: function(phone) {
    var masks = ['(00) 0000-0000', '(00) 00000-0000'];
    mask = phone.match(/^\([0-9]{2}\) 9/g)
        ? masks[1]
        : masks[0];
    $phone.mask(mask, this);
}};
$phone.mask('(00) 0000-0000', maskOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

**With jquery.mask.js**

http://jsfiddle.net/brynner/f9kd0aes/

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="phone" maxlength="15" value="85999998888">
<input type="text" class="phone" maxlength="15" value="8533334444">
```

JS

```
// Function
function phoneMask(e){
    var s=e.val();
    var s=s.replace(/[_\W]+/g,'');
    var n=s.length;
    if(n<11){var m='(00) 0000-00000';}else{var m='(00) 00000-00000';}
    $(e).mask(m);
}

// Type
$('body').on('keyup','.phone',function(){   
    phoneMask($(this));
});

// On load
$('.phone').keyup();
```

**Only jQuery**

http://jsfiddle.net/brynner/6vbrqe6z/

HTML

```
<p class="phone">85999998888</p>
<p class="phone">8599998888</p>
```

jQuery

```
$('.phone').text(function(i, text) {
    var n = (text.length)-6;
    if(n==4){var p=n;}else{var p=5;}
    var regex = new RegExp('(\\d{2})(\\d{'+p+'})(\\d{4})');
    var text = text.replace(regex, "($1) $2-$3");
    return text;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using the *change* event like this:

```
$("#phone")
.mask("(99) 9999?9-9999")
.on("change", function() {

    var last = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1 );

    if( last.length == 3 ) {
        var move = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") - 1, 1 );
        var lastfour = move + last;
        var first = $(this).val().substr( 0, 9 ); // Change 9 to 8 if you prefer mask without space: (99)9999?9-9999

        $(this).val( first + '-' + lastfour );
    }
})
.change(); // Trigger the event change to adjust the mask when the value comes setted. Useful on edit forms.
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it on blur is:

```
                        function formatPhone(obj) {
                        if (obj.value != "")
                        { 
                            var numbers = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, ''),
                            char = {0:'(',3:') ',6:' - '};
                            obj.value = '';
                            upto = numbers.length; 

                            if(numbers.length < 10) 
                            { 
                                upto = numbers.length; 
                            }
                            else
                            { 
                                upto = 10; 
                            }
                            for (var i = 0; i < upto; i++) {
                                obj.value += (char[i]||'') + numbers[i];
                            }
                        } 
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[As alternative](http://jsbin.com/defijo/5/edit?html,js,output)

```
    function FormatPhone(tt,e){
  //console.log(e.which);
  var t = $(tt);
  var v1 = t.val();
  var k = e.which;
  if(k!=8 && v1.length===18){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  var q = String.fromCharCode((96 <= k && k <= 105)? k-48 : k);
  if (((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) && e.keyCode!=46 && e.keyCode!=37 && e.keyCode!=8 && e.keyCode!=39) {
 e.preventDefault();
  }
  else{
    setTimeout(function(){
      var v = t.val();
      var l = v.length;
      //console.log(l);
      if(k!=8){
        if(l<4){
          t.val('+7 ');
        }
        else if(l===4){
          if(isNaN(q)){
            t.val('+7 (');
          }
          else{
            t.val('+7 ('+q);
          }
        }
        else if(l===7){
          t.val(v+')');
        }
        else if(l===9){
          t.val(v1+' '+q);
        }
        else if(l===13||l===16){
          t.val(v1+'-'+q);
        }
        else if(l>18){
          v=v.substr(0,18);
          t.val(v);
        }
        }
        else{
          if(l<4){
            t.val('+7 ');
          }
        }
    },100);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was developed simple and easy masks on input field to US phone format [**jquery-input-mask-phone-number**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-input-mask-phone-number)

Simple Add [**jquery-input-mask-phone-number**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-input-mask-phone-number) plugin in to your HTML file and call usPhoneFormat method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#yourphone').usPhoneFormat({
        format: '(xxx) xxx-xxxx',
    });   
});
```

Working JSFiddle Link https://jsfiddle.net/1kbat1nb/

NPM Reference URL https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-input-mask-phone-number

GitHub Reference URL https://github.com/rajaramtt/jquery-input-mask-phone-number

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to show your mask as placeholder you should use [jQuery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/).

The cleanest way:

```
var options =  {
    onKeyPress: function(phone, e, field, options) {
        var masks = ['(00) 0000-00000', '(00) 00000-0000'];
        var mask = (phone.length>14) ? masks[1] : masks[0];
        $('.phone-input').mask(mask, options);
    }
};

$('.phone-input').mask('(00) 0000-00000', options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes use this

```
$("#phone").inputmask({"mask": "(99) 9999 - 9999"});
```

[Link here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exNJwj)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.phone').focus(function(e) {
    // add mask
    $('.phone')
        .mask("(99) 99999999?9")
        .focusin(function(event)
        {
            $(this).unmask();
            $(this).mask("(99) 99999999?9");
        })
        .focusout(function(event)
        {
            var phone, element;
            element = $(this);
            phone = element.val().replace(/\D/g, '');
            element.unmask();

            if (phone.length > 10) {
                element.mask("(99) 99999-999?9");
            } else {
                element.mask("(99) 9999-9999?9");
            }
        }
    );
});
```