# How to change Phone Number string format in javascript:

Tags: javascript, string, format

I want to change the format of Phone Number in Javascript.

Means when someone type Phone Number(mobile or land line) on Number text box then i want to change its format before showing it on the page.

There are two formats in which i want to change the Phone Number string(in javascript) :-

1) {0:(###) ###-####}

2) {0:###-####}

> > I have tried some javascript functions but did not get the proper result.

FYI,I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 application.

Thanks

Comment: Mind showing us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Use phone number masking plugins...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phone mask with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery)

Comment: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ check this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jquery` phone number masking plugins for this.
For reference check the following links

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

http://randyburden.kodingen.com/wordpress/archives/154