# Format Textbox input for phone number MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.textboxfor

I am simply using a `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { id = "phoneNo")`

I am using a regex to limit it to 10 numbers only.

Is there a way I can format the textbox to appear like `(555) 444-3333` while they type, but in the model it will simply be passing the 10 numbers, like `5554443333`? I meant to automatically create those brackets and - while also checking using regex if they entered 10 numbers?

Comment: use a mask http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jquery as Matt said at his comment, stated at this question of the site: 
[Phone mask with jQuery and Masked Input Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery-and-masked-input-plugin)

Or with plain javascript, as explained by xxx here with alternatives too:
[Mask US phone number string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17651207/mask-us-phone-number-string-with-javascript)

List of alternatives coded for a example input called "phone":

1. Example code with plain javaScript:

```
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
```

2. Example code with jQuery but without adding any new dependence():

```
$('#phone', '#example-form')

.keydown(function (e) {
    var key = e.which || e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    $phone = $(this);

    // Don't let them remove the starting '('
    if ($phone.val().length === 1 && (key === 8 || key === 46)) {
        $phone.val('('); 
        return false;
    } 
    // Reset if they highlight and type over first char.
    else if ($phone.val().charAt(0) !== '(') {
        $phone.val('('+$phone.val()); 
    }

    // Auto-format- do not expose the mask as the user begins to type
    if (key !== 8 && key !== 9) {
        if ($phone.val().length === 4) {
            $phone.val($phone.val() + ')');
        }
        if ($phone.val().length === 5) {
            $phone.val($phone.val() + ' ');
        }           
        if ($phone.val().length === 9) {
            $phone.val($phone.val() + '-');
        }
    }

    // Allow numeric (and tab, backspace, delete) keys only
    return (key == 8 || 
            key == 9 ||
            key == 46 ||
            (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
            (key >= 96 && key <= 105)); 
})

.bind('focus click', function () {
    $phone = $(this);

    if ($phone.val().length === 0) {
        $phone.val('(');
    }
    else {
        var val = $phone.val();
        $phone.val('').val(val); // Ensure cursor remains at the end
    }
})

.blur(function () {
    $phone = $(this);

    if ($phone.val() === '(') {
        $phone.val('');
    }
});
```

3. Example code with jQuery using Masked Input Plugin:

```
$("#phone").mask("(99) 9999?9-9999");

$("#phone").on("blur", function() {
    var last = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") + 1 );

    if( last.length == 3 ) {
        var move = $(this).val().substr( $(this).val().indexOf("-") - 1, 1 );
        var lastfour = move + last;
        var first = $(this).val().substr( 0, 9 );

        $(this).val( first + '-' + lastfour );
    }
});
```