# Phone input mask with optional country code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I would like to create an input mask for phone numbers.  The majority of the phone numbers will look like (123) 456 - 7890.  I would like an optional country code and extension to be accepted when applicable.

(123) 456 -7890 x1234

+1 (123) 456 - 7890

+1 (123) 456 -7890 x1234

Am i able to do this with regex and jquery?

Comment: Dupe of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery-and-masked-input-plugin

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use this jquery plugin :

https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

```
$("#phone").intlTelInput();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/enx8ub4n/

With an example to validate user input :

https://intl-tel-input.com/node_modules/intl-tel-input/examples/gen/is-valid-number.html

Comment: I would like to use jquery.mask.  I just need help with the regular expression to accomplish the examples i provided above