# Validation form with a phone mask

Tags: javascript

I have a form with a phone mask, but I can’t make a red `borderColor` when all the phone numbers are not filled and green when everything is correct.

[image]

HTML

```
<form id="border1">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Phone number" class="phone_mask">
</form>
    <button id="button" class="form-button" onclick="checkNum(document.querySelector('.phone_mask'))">
        Sign up
    </button>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.maskedinput@1.4.1/src/jquery.maskedinput.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CSS

```
.phone_mask {
  border: 2px solid #eef0ef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 41px;
  width: 327px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 19px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  outline: none;
}

.phone_mask:focus {
  border: 2px solid #bdd9f7;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 3px #bdd9f7;
  height: 41px;
  width: 327px;
  outline: none;
}
```

JS

```
let phoneBlock = document.querySelector('.phone_mask')
let phone = $(".phone_mask").mask("+38(099)999-99-99");

function checkNum() {

    if (!phone) {
        phoneBlock.style.borderColor = 'red';
    }
    else {
        phoneBlock.style.borderColor = 'green'
    }

}
```

Help me please, thanks!

Comment: Note that the variable `phone` is initialized only once, without regard to the current form value. To fix simply check the actual form value inside the function

Comment: use [HTML pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_pattern.asp) for phone validation

Answer (score 1):

You **don't need** to use JavaScript for validating a phone pattern.

Instead, use input attribute `pattern` for validating a pattern and then adding a border to a valid pattern with pseudo-class `:valid`

Pattern in my code should be *+38-999-99-999*

```css
.phone_mask {
  border: 2px solid #eef0ef;
  border-radius: 3px;
  height: 41px;
  width: 327px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 19px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  outline: none;
}

.phone_mask:focus {
  border: 2px solid #bdd9f7;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 3px #bdd9f7;
  height: 41px;
  width: 327px;
  outline: none;
}

.phone_mask:valid {
  border: 2px solid limegreen;
}
```

```html
<form id="border1">
  <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone number" class="phone_mask" 
  pattern="[+]{1}[3]{1}[8]{1}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}" required>
  <button id="button" class="form-button" onclick="">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

For telephone numbers use `type="tel"`.

### `pattern` attribute in a nutshell:

- Use square brackets (`[]`) to specify what character (or range of characters should be there) - `[1-9]`/`[+]`/`[9]`
- After that, use wiggly brackets (`{}`) to specify how many of those characters should be there - `{1}`, `{2}` etc.
- Between you can add separators - (`-` or `/`)

---

If you strictly want to use `.mask` jQuery, here you go:

[Phone mask with jQuery and Masked Input Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery-and-masked-input-plugin)

Learn more:

[Pattern attribute and input types](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

Comment: @Marta Sure thing. If my answer did help you, consider checking it as a valid answer to your question by clicking "check" mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

the pattern property in HTML input tags is your friend here
The pattern is a regular expression, you could also use stuff like `\w` for word characters and `\d` for digits
for more about REGEX check [this cheat sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html)
don't forget to escape parenthesis , braces or point with a \ if you need them

in CSS you can use the `:valid` and `:invalid` selectors to style the different states of your inputs

the `:invalid` selector won't kick in unless your user clicks submit with invalid data in the targeted input

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I said?

Comment: Yeah just gave him a resource to do some research
i believe it's always better to encourage effort rather than give away a ready copy paste code