# Alphanumeric string format to specific pattern in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I achieve the following in typescript angular?

```
var specimenNumber = '19S20010';

// format to specific pattern 
format(specimenNumber, "***-****-*");

// expected output : 19S-2001-0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phone mask with jQuery and Masked Input Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633726/phone-mask-with-jquery-and-masked-input-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I found this in taiga-ui library

[Typescript code](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/taiga-ui/blob/main/projects/core/utils/format/format-number.ts)

[demo](https://taiga-ui.dev/utils/format)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this you can use any pattern with no regex used:

```js
var specimenNumber = '19S20010';

// format to specific pattern 
console.log(format(specimenNumber, "***-****-*"));

function format(number, mask) {
   var s = ''+number, r = '';
   for (var im=0, is = 0; im<mask.length && is<s.length; im++) {
     r += mask.charAt(im)=='*' ? s.charAt(is++) : mask.charAt(im);
   }
   return r;
}
```

Comment: Simple and clean. much helpful. thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :)