# Insert '-' every 5 characters as users type [like a product key]

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Auto-format structured data (phone, date) using jQuery plugin (or failing that vanilla JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109854/auto-format-structured-data-phone-date-using-jquery-plugin-or-failing-that-v)
>   [Insert space after certain character into javascript string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579584/insert-space-after-certain-character-into-javascript-string)

I am trying to write a script that handles product keys like the ones you see on the back of software and games.

I would like so when the user is inputing their key code the '-' are inserted every 5 characters for 5 sets of characters. Ex(`ABCDE-FGHIJ-KLMNO-PQRST-UVWXY`). So when the user enters `ABCDE` as soon as the '`E`' is enetered a '`-`' is inserted immeditly after via jQuery or JavaScript.

Thanks In Advance.
Comment if you have any questions or if I was unclear :)

Form:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
<p>Key: <input name="key" id="key" size="40"></p>
<p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want to post your code?

Comment: There are a few ways to resolve that one.  Personally, I think that using multiple input boxes, separate by dashes, works best. Jumping between the input boxes is a lot easier than trying to make "formatted controls" work like native ones.

Comment: multiple input boxes with a limit of 5 characters that jumps you to the next is IMHO a better idea.

Comment: Will the keys ever contain a `-`

Comment: @Dagon I am liking those ideas but can any of you provide a snippet of js that will hop from box to box after 5 characters?

Comment: @Dagon I can `:P` Give me a minute, OP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#key").mask("aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa");
});
```

Comment: so just to confirm  $("#key").mask("99999-99999-9999-99999-99999"); with the masked plugin should work?

Comment: yes .. it would work .. you can create different formats but 999 is for numbers only

Answer (score 2):

How about using http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

With that plugin, the following:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#key").mask("99999-99999-99999-99999-99999",{placeholder:" "});
});
```

or, if your key is all letters use:

```
$("#key").mask("aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa-aaaaa",{placeholder:" "});
```

or, if it's alpha/numeric use:

```
$("#key").mask("*****-*****-*****-*****-*****",{placeholder:" "});
```

Comment: See answer of Baba, he was quicker ;)

Comment: Typing on an iPad while watching football is not so quick ;-)

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<fieldset id="productkey">
    <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5">
    <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5">
    <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5">
    <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5">
    <input type="text" size="5" maxlength="5">
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( '#productkey' ).on( 'keyup', 'input', function () {
    if ( this.value.length === 5 ) {
        $( this ).next().focus();            
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XXLND/3/show/

You can also enhance the code, so that when the last text-box is filled out, a processing mechanism is activated:

```
$( '#productkey' ).on( 'keyup', 'input', function () {
    var $field = $( this );

    if ( $field.val().length === 5 ) {
        if ( $field.is( ':last-of-type' ) ) {
            $field.blur();
            processKey();              
        } else {
            $field.next().focus();            
        }
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XXLND/4/show/

Comment: +1 for `:last-of-type`

Comment: This doesn't let you shift-tab to the previous input.

Answer (score 2):

Simply because I don't like JQuery :)

```
function insertSpace(string, part, maxParts) {
    "use strict";
    var buffer = string.split("-"), step, i;
    for (i = 0; i < buffer.length; i += 1) {
        step = buffer[i];
        if (step.length > part) {
            buffer[i] = step.substr(0, part);
            buffer[i + 1] = step.substr(part) + (buffer[i + 1] || "");
        } else if (step.length < part) {
            if (i == buffer.length - 1) {
                if (!step) {
                    buffer.pop();
                }
            } else {
                buffer[i + 1] = step + (buffer[i + 1] || "");
                buffer.splice(i, 1);
                i -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    buffer.length = Math.min(maxParts, buffer.length);
    return buffer.join("-");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
// binds to both the 'keyup' and 'paste' events
$('input:text').on('keyup paste', function(e) {
    var that = $(this), // caches the $(this)
        val = that.val(), // access the value of the current input
        key = e.which, // determines which key was pressed
        allowed = [8, 46, 9, 16]; // defines 'allowed' keys (for editing/focusing)
                                  // backspace, delete, tab, shift
        if ($.inArray(key, allowed) == -1) {
            // if the pressed key is *not* an 'allowed' key
            if (val.length == 5) {
                // focuses the next element
                that.next().focus();
            }
            else if (val.length > 5) {
                // truncates the string, if greater than 5 characters
                that.val(val.substring(0, 5));
                that.next().focus();
            }
        }
});​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/JQQ9Z/1/).

The advantage of this approach is that rather than masking or manipulating the entered string, and accounting for multiple edge-cases, you're simply aiding the user by moving the focus at the right point. And, in this case, also allowing the user to refocus the re-edit the previously entered data.

Answer (score 0):

two things:

One the user experience side, I would avoid dynamically adding character in the input field as the user type a code. Depending on the environment you run the risk to interfere with what the user type.
However, the '-' helps user typing the code since this is a reference point for him. So I would suggest to have an input field and to show a pretty version of the code next to it (or make the field invisible and manage the focus of the field yourself).

For the php code, instead of adding a character every 5 characters I would do the opposite and simplify the code by removing all the unnecessary characters.
Something like that

```
if ( str_replace('-', '', $userInputKey)==str_replace('-', '', $officialKey) {
 echo 'Yeah! Valid key!';
}
```

Comment: `str_replace` is PHP he wants a java-script solution