# JavaScript automatic comma

Tags: javascript, regex

In my program, the user enters values betweeen 0 and 8.

For example: if the user wants to input "3,4" he only needs to write "34". the program will eventually put the comma in, but I have no clue how to do it.

So:

- input = "34"  --> output = "3,4"
- input = "09" --> output = "0,9"

This is what i tried, but of course it will accept "34" as integer:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

I also tried to split the input, but when the user inputs a integer like 3, it doesn't work anymore.

There's no deeper meaning to this problem, but to make the user input faster.

Comment: `x.toString().split('').join(',')`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556051/insert-every-5-characters-as-users-type-like-a-product-key this post might give you some clue..

Comment: I tired this before Zach, it works ony for numbers > 1.
if the user inputs "09" it will make it up as "9", unfortunatly.

Comment: Your problem is that you want a comma after every number? If that is so then remove the 3 in that function in regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. Convert the input number to a string ([`toString`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp));
2. Split the string between each character into an array ([`split`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp));
3. Join the elements of this array, separated by `,` ([`join`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)).

Here you are the full code:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().split("").join(",");
}
```

Comment: thanks, my error was that i parsed the user input first into a number and then i tried to add a comma.

that works for numbers like "34" but not for "09" because it will automatically make a "9" out of it.

Comment: If that's coming from a text input box you shouldn't even need to `toString` it. The textbox value will already be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is a bit overkill here isn't it?

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x < 10 ? x.toString() : x.toString().split('').join(',');
}
```